# Assembly Versioning and Dll Versioning in Team City

Tags: dll, teamcity, versioning, .net-assembly

I want to have these Versions in a format

like this.. {Major}.{Minor}.{Build}.{patch}

how to set this in the assembly info patcher in team city?

so that it will automatically increment the versions for each time it builds...

i want some guidance and help in this...?!?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

TeamCity can version assemblies for you with the *AssemblyInfo Patcher* build feature.  To take advantage of this:

1. Create a build parameter called `%Major.Minor%`.  Set this manually to some value, e.g. `1.0`.
2. On the *General Settings* tab, set the `Build number format` to `%Major.Minor%.%build.vcs.number%.%build.counter%`.
3. On the *Build Steps* tabe, scroll to the *Additional Build Features* at the bottom of the page. Add an *Assembly Info Patcher* build step. It will default to using the `%system.build.number%`, which you've defined in step 2.

This will result in all of your assemblies being versioned with the `%system.build.number%`, which includes the Major and Minor version, the VCS revision, and TeamCity's incremental build number.

Comment: Hi sarathprasath, do you need any more help with this?

Comment: The thing is that I would like to keep all numbers "as is" in AssemblyInfoVersion _except_ the build number. The only number I want the AssemblyInfoPatcher to set is the build number, is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

Using the **File Content Replacer** build feature suggested by Paul, we eventually ended up with the following versioning scheme in our project:

http://www.meadow.se/wordpress/generating-semantic-version-build-numbers-in-teamcity/

A little bit complicated to setup but we're happy with the results.

/Emil

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question from Emil G about keeping the first numbers of the version from AssemblyInfo, it's currently not possible: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-20475

Would be nice, though.

/Emil Å

Comment: This appears to have been added just a few days after you posted this answer, as part of [TeamCity 9.1](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/File+Content+Replacer#FileContentReplacer-Changingonlythelastversionpart/buildnumberoftheAssemblyVersionattribute:).

Comment: Thanks, that's valuable information indeed! Will surely check it out.

Answer (score 0):

It's now possible to be done through the File Content Replacer (available since TeamCity 9.1): https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/File+Content+Replacer