# How can I get TeamCity to read my assembly version

Tags: .net, teamcity, nuget, teamcity-7.1

...and make it accessible so I can use it in a (NuGet) Build Step?

I don't see anything from the assembly in the huge parameters list (accessible by clicking the small "more" icon to the right of the text input control).

Edit: Screenshot available [here](http://t.co/ojbV5e8phh)

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider allowing TeamCity to set the assembly version for you?  If so, you might check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252282) to a similar question. It  describes a method for setting the version number when the build starts, and then applying that version to your assemblies when they're built.